# Get gallery elements

Tags: android, android-gallery

I've created a gallery, and now I want to change it in the code. The element of the gallery consists of two `Textviews` and i want to get the number of lines.

I tried:

```
TextView top = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.top);
top.getLineCount();
```

But the app crashed at `top.getLineCount();`Does anyone have an idea?

GetView of CustomAdapter

```
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater iteminflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
       View gallaryitem = iteminflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
       ImageView imgView= (ImageView ) gallaryitem .findViewById(R.id.item);
       imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);


       //TextView top = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top);
       //top.getLineCount();





       return gallaryitem ;
   }
```

LayoutFile

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10px" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#4E4E4E"/>


<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/bottom" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="moremore" 
    android:textSize="27sp"

    android:layout_marginTop="275dip"
    android:paddingTop="35dip"
    android:textColor="#eeeeee"
    android:background="#60000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans"/>

 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/top" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="testtesttesttesttesttesttest" 
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:textColor="#eeeeee"
    android:background="#60ff0000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you putting the Textview line of code at in your gallery??

Comment: I add the CustomAdapter and Layoutfile

Comment: Whats the error you get when it crashes

Comment: how can I find out the error?

Comment: The debug view in android..Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a custom adapter for modifying the children of your gallery.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<E>{
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, E[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if( convertView== null ) convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

            //Modify contents of your gallery here.. example:
            TextView top = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.top);
            top.getLineCount();

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Set it on your gallery the way you set a normal adapter:

```
myGallery.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(...));
```

Comment: when I add this two lines of code to my customadapter, the app crashs ...'ve got an idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you have the TextView in the layout you want to populate the gallery? If it can't find the view you'll be trying to get the lineCount of a null.

Comment: I add the CustomAdapter and Layoutfile

Comment: In your code, you inflate your view to "gallaryitem", but look for the textView in convertView, which might be null, use gallaryitem.findViewById() instead.

Comment: You should also use the convertView unless it is null, to avoid unnecessary inflation/instantiation.

Comment: ok thanks, it works with the "gallaryitem (sorry for spelling :) )
but how can I change a specific item?

Comment: We are getting a bit off topic here, but it depends on how you want to change it. If you want to change the underlying text/image/whatever you want to display, just change it in the array or list that contains it and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter (you don't have to do anything *in* the adapter. If you want something along the lines of "every third item shall have a green background", you do that in the getView() method. You would check if the current item (get it with getItem(position)) fits the criteria, and then change it accordingly.

Comment: ok thanks, sorry but I'm new in android. getItem() returns me a Object, and how can I get my Textview "top" from that?
Thanks man for helping!

Comment: calling getItem() returns one of the items you supplied to the adapter (from your array or list that is). To get a view that is in the list (your view "top" for example) just do like in my answer; call findViewById() on your convertView, which contains the views available in the layout you supplied to the adapter.

Comment: yea but when I call findViewById() I don't can decide on which position of the gallery the view is?

Comment: When you call findViewById() in the adapter, you have the `position` attribute that tells you in which position the view is.

Comment: THANKS MAN! Finally I got it... thanks for being patient youre a great guy!

Comment: Glad I could help, and good luck with your programming.
Just a little hint; you should accept the answer if you find it satisfying, so it gets closed.